# Creating an array for each column of a data frame by column name

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to create a number of arrays that correspond to the data values of each column in a large data frame, and I want each array to share the same name as its corresponding column. Here is an example of how I am trying to approach this:

```
x = [a b c] <- column names
    [1 2 3]
    [1 2 3]
```

`names = [a b c]`

`For i in names:`

```
i = numpy.array(x[i])
```

I want to create three arrays (a, b, and c):

```
a = [1, 1]
b = [2, 2]
c = [3, 3]
```

But all I'm getting is one array:

```
i = [3, 3]
```

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time in the for loop you assign a different value to the same variable so when the loop finishes you are left with the last assigned value.

I would recommend that you create a dictionary and use each name as the key and the array as value:

```
arrays = {}
for i in names:
    arrays[i] = numpy.array(x[i])
```

Then you can retrieve each array with:

```
arrays[name]
```

Answer (score 1):

With your iteration, the following happens:

```
i = 'a'
i = np.array([1, 1])
i = 'b'
i = np.array([2, 2])
i = 'c'
i = np.array([3, 3])
```

Then when you `print i`, you're only left with what you set for `i` in the ***last step*** of iteration.  You likely want something like:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1], 'b':[2,2], 'c':[3,3]})
a, b, c = [np.array(df[i]) for i in df.columns]
```

Then you get

```
print a
#array([1, 1])
print b
#array([2, 2])
print c
#array([3, 3])
```

---

If you don't know the column names beforehand, you can create a dictionary where each key-value pair in the dictionary will be `name`:`array`.  The simplest way to do this is

```
arrays = dict(df.iteritems())
```

or if you don't want the index:

```
arrays = dict(zip(df.columns, df.as_matrix().T))
```

Then you can retrieve the arrays by name doing `arrays['a']`. However, I'm not sure why you would want this functionality over being able to get the close to the same thing by calling `df.a` or `df['a']`.

Answer (score 1):

Using only NumPy, you can use structured arrays:

```
test = np.array([(1,2,3), (1,2,3), (1,2,3)], dtype=[('a', float), ('b', float), ('c', float)])
```

such that:

```
print(test['a'])
#array([ 1.,  1.,  1.])
```